# How to redirect multiple URLs to respective another URL with single parameter change?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have requirement to redirect many URLs are below:

www.example.com/test1/test2/P-b1_l1_id_c1_c1-10551-***10051***-74560-en
 to 
www.example.com/test1/test2/P-b1_l1_id_c1_c1-10551-***10551***-74560-en

just a change 10051 to 10551.

I could have done simple redirect but there are many URL with same requirement. So looking if there is any solution which can replace 10551-***10051***- to 10551-***10551***- for all pages which have 10551-***10051***- in the URL.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: ¿Do all strings have exactly the same format and is `10051` always in the same position in them?

Comment: @faa..Yes it is in same position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea using mod_rewrite directives in the .htaccess file in root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)-10551-10051-(.*)/?
RewriteRule .*   %1-10551-10551-%2   [R=301,L]
```

### UPDATE

```
# Enable rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On
# Specify the URL prefix
RewriteBase /
# Prevent loops
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Match any URL the holds this string: -10551-10051-, splitting it in 3 parts
# The segment before the string to match, the string itself and the next segment up to the first slash or nothing 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)-10551-10051-([^/]+)/?
# Assemble the substitution URL like this: first segment-modified string-last segment. Rewrite.
RewriteRule .*   %1-10551-10551-%2   [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect

`http://example.com/Folder1/Folder2/anything1-10551-10051-anything2`

To:

`http://example.com/Folder1/Folder2/anything1-10551-10551-anything2`

I assumed you want a permanent and visible redirection. If that's not the case, remove `R=301` in `[R=301,L]`

Comment: thanks @faa..i want to make it generic..like my rewrite shloud work for other URLs also..example www.example.com/test3/test4/P-b1_l1_id_c1_c1-10551-10551-74560-en
www.example.com/test5/test6/P-b1_l1_id_c1_c1-10551-10551-74560-en
should also redirect in similar fashion..As there are many URLs, i want to create single redirect for all.

Comment: @Divya1987 Yes. But in both of your last examples the number to replace is `10551`. The rule replaces `10051` with `10551`. If it is the other way around, please confirm to modify the rule.

Comment: I am using below rule:                              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)-10551-10051-(.*)/? [NC] RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1-10551-10551-$2 [L,R=301] but output is not correct . output is comming as: http://www.example.com/////////////////////test1/test2/P-b1_l1_id_c1_c1-10551-10551-74560-en-10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051--10551-10051- Please help

Comment: did u get my question? above i have mentioned my code. Please let me know if thats not much clear.

Comment: I did not see it complete. But, that can't work ¿What's wrong with the rules in my answer. They are tested and work?

Comment: Somehow your rule is not working. When 10551-10551 are together only then redirect should happen to change it 10551-10051. So i modified your rule to 10551-10051 as RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)-10551-10051-(.*)/? [NC] RewriteRule (.*) example.com/$1-10551-10551-$2 [L,R=301] but even this is not working.

Comment: I did not understand that part. My question is: ¿Do the rules work when `10551-10551` are not together? That would be easy to correct but I have to know first if they work.

Comment: nothing happened after applying your rule. Redirect not working

Comment: Whatever it is the reason, can be corrected. Could you please copy-paste in a comment the complete URL you are using to test?

Comment: Well, that's a very powerful reason. I designed the rule for an incoming URL like the one in your question: `http://www.example.com/test1/test2/P-b1_l1_id_c1_c1-10551-10051-74560-en`. So, there is no way it can work. If you want to further explain in your question how is the whole process, I will be glad to help if I can.

Comment: Got it. Let me see if I can convert that to a rule and I will update my answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Divya1987 Updated. Please give it a try and let me know. I also tested it.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with the answer, you should consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it, selecting the check mark in the upper left of this answer.

Comment: Can you also explain this rule...?

Comment: Sure. I will do it in the answer.

Comment: Can you please explain in detail this part ***-([^/]+)/?***

Comment: Matches everything but slash. That way the trailing slash can be omitted in the rule, if present. In this case is really important because strings with and without trailing slash are not the same for the script that GETs them.

Comment: One of the most important features of mod_rewrite, is the capability to process regular expressions. The directives alone are not enough. Here is a [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorialcnt.html) to a good tutorial so you can get more familiar with Regex.